# check if list element is equal to any other element in list using for-loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, for-loop

I'm having this class:

```
public class SortOrderModel
{
    public string IdSort { get; set; }
    public List<ContentPage> ContentPages { get; set; }
}
```

The above class that have the listpropery is a list of this class:

```
public class ContentPage
{
public string Id { get; set; }
public string ParentReference { get; set; }
public string Url { get; set; }
public int SortOrder { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I'm having this for-loop, witch have the class SortOrderModel as @model for the view.
I now want to check in the first if-statement: If Model.ContentPages[i].ParentReference is equal to Any Url-propery in the whole Model.ContentPages-list. Iv'e tried so many ways but don't know how to solve it.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.ContentPages.Count; i++)
            {
            <ul>
                    if (Model.ContentPages[i].ParentReference == TODO) <-------
                    {
                        <li style="padding-left: 80px;">@Model.ContentPages[i].Title @Html.TextBoxFor(o => Model.ContentPages[i].SortOrder, new { @class = "sortBox" })</li>

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li style="padding-left: 40px;">@Model.ContentPages[i].Title @Html.TextBoxFor(o => Model.ContentPages[i].SortOrder, new { @class = "sortBox" })</li>

                    }

            </ul>
            }
```

Comment: You should tag the appropriate language. Also if this is asp.net MVC, there is a specific tag for that too.

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie... Added some tags now. Thank you @crashmstr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if (Model.ContentPages.Any(m => m.Url == Model.ContentPages[i].ParentReference))
```

Be careful about lazy loading and multiple enumerations, though. Things like `Count` and `Any` will cause a new query each time a different variation is called, if all the items haven't been queried already. If you cast `Model.ContentPages` to a list first, though, then the count and other LINQ queries will be run on the same already-queried, in-memory list. For example:

```
var contentPages = Model.ContentPages.ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < contentPages.Count(); i++)
{
    <ul>
        if (contentPages.Any(m => m.Url == contentPages[i].ParentReference))
        {
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It does what I asked for. So Thank you! But when running the code a figured out that it was something else I wanted to do. But thanks anyway

Comment: Again, thanks for your answer! But like I said, I figured out that I was out for something else. So I posted a new question with the things I want to achieve. Please take a look if you want! =) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793257/render-a-treeview-using-a-for-loop?noredirect=1#comment36595609_23793257)