# Render a treeview using a for-loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, for-loop

I'm having this class:

```
public class SortOrderModel
{
    public string IdSort { get; set; }
    public List<ContentPage> ContentPages { get; set; }
}
```

The above class that have the listpropery is a list of this class:

```
public class ContentPage
{
public string Id { get; set; }
public string ParentReference { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

And let's say I'm sending in SortOrderModel as @model to a view.

And in the view: Model.ContentPages, is a List of 5 ContentPage with the values:

```
var home = new ContentPage()
{
    Id = "ContentPages/1",
    Title = "Home",
    ParentReference = "/",
    SortOrder = "0"
};

var about = new ContentPage()
{
    Id = "ContentPages/2",
    Title = "About",
    ParentReference = "ContentPages/1",
    SortOrder = "1"
};

var contactinfo = new ContentPage()
{
    Id = "ContentPages/3",
    Title = "ContactInfo",
    ParentReference = "ContentPages/2",
    SortOrder = "0"
};

var allProducts = new ContentPage()
{
    Id = "ContentPages/4",
    Title = "AllProducts",
    ParentReference = "ContentPages/1",
    SortOrder = "2"
};

var product1 = new ContentPage()
{
    Id = "ContentPages/5",
    Title = "Product1",
    ParentReference = "ContentPages/4",
    SortOrder = "0"
};

    var product2 = new ContentPage()
{
    Id = "ContentPages/6",
    Title = "Product1",
    ParentReference = "ContentPages/4",
    SortOrder = "1"
};
```

How can I render a treeview with these values using a for-loop, so it looks like something like this:

```
> Home
    > About
        > ContactInfo
    > AllProducts
        > Product1
        > Product2
```

It's very important to use a for-loop, because I'm gonna use it in a view with @Html.TextBoxFor for the SortOrder-Properties so I can change the sortOrder values of each object. And as far as I know I need to use a for-loop and not a foreach to get the model-binding to work, because i'm sending the values to a [HttpPost]-method.

This is my attempt to do it:

```
@model CMS_Affiliate_Web.Models.SortOrderModel
@{
string startPageId = "";
foreach (var pageId in Model.ContentPages.Where(o => o.Url == "/").Select(o => o.Id))
{
    startPageId = pageId;
}
}
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("SortOrderMenu", "secure", Model.ContentPages, FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(o => Model.IdSort)

            var contentPages = Model.ContentPages.ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < contentPages.Count(); i++)
            {
                <ul>

                    @if (Model.ContentPages[i].Url == "/" || Model.ContentPages[i].ParentReference == startPageId)
                    {
                        <li>@Model.ContentPages[i].Title @Html.TextBoxFor(o => Model.ContentPages[i].SortOrder, new {@class = "sortBox"})</li>
                    }
                    else if (contentPages.Any(m => m.Id == contentPages[i].ParentReference))
                    {
                        <li style="padding-left: 80px; color: red;">@Model.ContentPages[i].Title @Html.TextBoxFor(o => Model.ContentPages[i].SortOrder, new {@class = "sortBox"})</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            }
            <div class="activity-desk">
                <input type="submit" value="Spara ny sortering" class="btn btn-primary" name="saveSliders" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</li>
```

But it renders it like this, not what I want:

```
> Home
    > About
    > AllProducts
        > Product1
        > Product2
        > ContactInfo
```

EDIT!

```
@model Models.SortOrderModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "SortOrderMenu";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@helper RenderItems(string parentID, int indent = 0)
{
@Html.HiddenFor(o => Model.IdSort)
int index = ViewBag.ItemIndex ?? 0;
foreach (var contentPage in Model.ContentPages
    .Where(p => p.ParentReference == parentID)
    .OrderBy(p => p.SortOrder))
{
    <li style="padding-left: @(indent)px; color: red;">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => Model.ContentPages[index].Id)
        @contentPage.Title
        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => Model.ContentPages[index].SortOrder,
            new {@class = "sortBox"})
    </li>
    ViewBag.ItemIndex = ++index;
    @RenderItems(contentPage.Id, indent + 20)
    ;
    index = ViewBag.ItemIndex;
}
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SortOrderMenu", "secure", Model.ContentPages, FormMethod.Post))
{
@RenderItems("ContentPages/6401")

<div class="activity-desk">
    <input type="submit" value="Spara ny sortering" class="btn btn-primary" name="saveSliders"    />
</div>
}
```

EDIT 2 ---------------

```
@helper RenderItems(string parentID, int indent = 0)
{
@Html.HiddenFor(o => Model.IdSort)
int index = ViewBag.ItemIndex ?? 0;
foreach (var contentPage in Model.ContentPages
                                 .Where(p => p.ParentReference == parentID)
                                 .OrderBy(p => p.SortOrder))
{

    <li style="padding-left: @(indent)px; color: red;">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => Model.ContentPages[index].Id)
        @contentPage.Title
        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => Model.ContentPages[index].SortOrder,
                                 new { @class = "sortBox" })
    </li>
    ViewBag.ItemIndex = ++index;
    @RenderItems(contentPage.Id, indent + 20);
                                           index = ViewBag.ItemIndex;
}
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SortOrderMenu", "secure", Model.ContentPages, FormMethod.Post))
{
@RenderItems("/")

<div class="activity-desk">
    <input type="submit" value="Spara ny sortering" class="btn btn-primary" name="saveSliders" />
</div>
}
```

ControllerMethods:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SortOrderMenu()
    {
        var allContentPages = RavenSession.Query<ContentPage>().ToList();

        var sortOrderModel = new SortOrderModel();
        sortOrderModel.ContentPages = allContentPages;


        return View(sortOrderModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SortOrderMenu(SortOrderModel model)
    {
        foreach (var page in model.ContentPages)
        {
            var contPage = RavenSession.Load<ContentPage>(page.Id);

            contPage.SortOrder = page.SortOrder;
            RavenSession.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("SortOrderMenu");
    }
```

Comment: Please place example of your attempt first.

Comment: Have added a example of my attemt now, @Cubicle.Jockey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would end up with following recursive helper:

```
@helper RenderItems(string parentID, int indent = 0)
{
    foreach (var contentPage in Model.ContentPages
                                     .Where(p => p.ParentReference == parentID)
                                     .OrderBy(p => p.SortOrder))
    {
        var index = Model.ContentPages.IndexOf(contentPage);
        <li style="padding-left: @(indent)px; color: red;">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(o => Model.ContentPages[index].Id)
            @contentPage.Title
            @Html.TextBoxFor(o => Model.ContentPages[index].SortOrder,
                new { @class = "sortBox" })
        </li>
        @RenderItems(contentPage.Id, indent + 20)
    }
}
```

For usage just call it on your view like this:

```
@RenderItems("/");
```

EDIT:
Alternatively you could use hidden input with Model.ContentPages.Index as name for defining your index:

```
@helper  RenderItems(string parentID, int indent = 0)
{
    foreach (var contentPage in Model.ContentPages
                                     .Where(p => p.ParentReference == parentID)
                                     .OrderBy(p => p.SortOrder))
    {
        var index = Guid.NewGuid();
        <input type="hidden" name="Model.ContentPages.Index" value="@(index)" />
        <li style="padding-left: @(indent)px; color: red;">
            @contentPage.Title 
            <input type="text" class="sortBox" 
                   name="Model.ContentPages[@(index)].SortOrder" 
                   value="@contentPage.SortOrder" />
        </li>
        @RenderItems(contentPage.Id, indent + 20)
    }
}
```

[More details about it in Phil Haack's great blog post about collection binding](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Comment: Thank you! Fantastic work! It renders perfect. =) But how am I gonna be able to use this in a html.beginform to post it to a [httpPost]-method. Because my goal is to be able to update the SortOrder-values

Comment: Thanks again! But I found something that doesn't match. The sortOrder-values that is written out in the textboxes doesn't match with it's data. How can I fix this?

Comment: I've tried it in a html.beginform, but the values passed to the [httppost]-metod doesn't get right. From my created inctances of my sample code it only posts a list of the contentpages with the parentreference "ContentPages/1" to the [httppost]-method. Please help me =)

Comment: Yes, there was a bug with index because it copied by value in .NET and every version of RenderItems function has his own index. I have tried to use ViewBag shared storage for iterating, code now looks a little bit verbose, but you're welcome to try it.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. But it still doesn't work. The sortOrder-values displaying for each contentpage is wrong. Seens to be some kind of problem with: int index

Comment: Did you tryied an updated version of method with ViewBag? It should work, I just checked it by posting the form with RenderItems("/"). If it doesn't work - look how your code differs from mine or post your code into question so I can see it.

Comment: I posted the code I use in the view to my question under EDIT, doesn't work correct. @RenderItems("ContentPages/6401") is the id of my startPage

Comment: The view code should be fine. How does your post action definition look? Is it accept SortOrderModel or List<ContentPage>?

Comment: Now I've updated my question with under EDIT 2 (included the controller-methods to). Everything width all this new code i posted saves everything correct in the database. But the problem is that the displayed values in the textboxes are wrong. Even if I change them and save, they are saved corecttly. But It still displays wrong values in view. It also added a textbox for each Id, but they are also displayed wrong. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: oh, I see. Just changed the logic for calculating the index of item by IndexOf method. Note that second (alternative) way should also work.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.. the textbox-values are being saved. But the textboxes are displayed on the wrong rows and also the wrong value are then being saved

Comment: I've added var index = Model.ContentPages.IndexOf(contentPage); and removed all stuff with ViewBag.ItemIndex.

Comment: Everything works fantastic now! Thank you very very mutch for solving this problem! Thanks for taking your time. =)